# Measuring MBPS Per Device

Tags: internet

How can I tell how much bandwidth each machine is using in my home?

I was doing some internet speed tests from various areas in my home. My roommate started watching a youtube video and found myself curious if I could tell what mbps he was using vs. me.

I have a mac if it matters.

Comment: You need access to the router that both of you are using.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand how your internet/networking operates.  Your roommate did not use some fraction of the bandwidth while you performed a test. Rather the connection is shared time-wise.  Your Ethernet frames are sent at full speed on the wire, but may be interspersed with Ethernet frames for other activities such as your roommate's.  When your speed test ***averages out*** the transfer rates **over time**, you end up with a lowered throughput number.  That number is smaller because of extended time, not reduced transfer speed.

Answer (score 0):

Thete is no single, easy answer to this question as it depends on many factors.

To accurately determine this you likely need a router that can support per-device traffic stats and look at those - this is not typical on SOHO routers,

If you flash your router with dd-wrt or openwrt bwmon can give you usagr stats per device, or you can use iptables rulrs and dcripts to roll your own.  More complex mechanisms use rflow or similar to log packets to a device on your network which can then be processed and graphed.

Comment: If it's hard to measure, is it possible to guess? Before he started watching the YT video, I noticed my download speed was about 450 mbps. Once he started watching, it seemed like it was closer to 350 - 370 mbps. Is it reasonable to assume he was using ~100 mbps for his yt video? Or is that just regular variation?

Comment: A youtube video would use way less then that unless its an 8k video which would be extremely rare. Even a 4k video uses only 32mbit while full hd (1080p) use about 3 mbit.  If you have wifi there may be a lot of collissions taking place slowing down thinfs, or it could be qos at your isp or other things.

Comment: When you say collisions, what do you mean? QOs = quotas?

Comment: Collissions occur, for instance, when 2 wifi devices transmit at the same time (on the same channel). This corrupts both signals and they need to retry. QOS = Quality of Service which is a way of guaranteeing minim throughput / priotitising traffic while divying up bandwidth where thr total available is less then the total that can be used - eg 10 people have 500 megabit connections but all share a 2000 megabit upstrram connection - using QoS allows fairer divying up of the connection.